# Selenium / Python - Selecting an element id by a stored variable

Tags: python, selenium

Issue: Unable to select an element id object using a stored variable.

Situation: I need to open a page, make a selection, store that selection in a variable `card_id` and next, find the element on the last page with the id `pick_id` and the stored variable, and click it. Hope I am being clear on this situation. If not, please just ask. I have tried to find the Selenium API documentation to handle this, nope.

Test Code:

```
def test_00_validation_test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id("first_page").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("make_pick").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@name='64'])[2]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("save_pick").click()
        self.assertEqual("Pick Was Saved", self.close_alert_and_get_its_text())
        card_id = driver.find_element_by_id("testingNum").get_attribute("value")
        driver.find_element_by_id("confirm_pick_page").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("pick_id", card_id).click()
```

Comment: if you pass the id and selenium doesnt find it, its probably not in the html. if you are 100% its in the html it may be in an iframe. cant help you without knowing exactly what you too.

Comment: what do you mean by driver.find_element_by_id("pick_id", card_id) ? you cannot pass two arguments to this function. Please explain what you are trying to achieve in this function.

Comment: @user1411110 That is exactly right. I tried to cheat my way around it with the 2nd argument. Nope. I tried like this `driver.find_element_by_id("pick_id").click(card_id)` as well, nope. I know those aren't valid, but was hoping as I can not find another way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Also, for the 'what am I trying to achieve' question. Each pick I make is stored on the server, we hide that in the HTML as `testingNum` just for testing purposes, with the value it is being assigned. I get and store that value as `card_id`. So, when I go to the `confirm_pick_page` I can find it associated to the `pick_id` element.

Answer (score 1):

Ok from your explanation i think you want to go  the element pick_id then drill down and look for card_id and click on it. This could be done as:

```
card_id = driver.find_element_by_id("testingNum").get_attribute("value")
pick_id = driver.find_element_by_id("pick_id")
pick_id.find_element_by_id(card_id).click()
```

You can always find an element and then drill down that element using `find_element_by`.

Comment: That will, and does, give `NoSuchElementException`. The `card_id` is a stored variable, and the usage of `pick_id` from your example is using it as you would `driver.`, will not work. Just for the hell of it, I tried and it failed. Thanks for assisting though!

Comment: Is there another way to use the `find_element_by_id` function with 3 arguments, or another function that will take an element with the stored vale?